# Accessing a DB File on a computer from a HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, entity-framework-core, hololens

## HoloLens File Access

Key Points:

- HoloLens 2 Device that is plugged in to a computer via data cable
- Existing SQLite DB on that computer located under Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData (C:/Program Files)
- Unfortunately, the file must stay in C:/Program Files and be accessible to the HL2 due to other requirements.
- The HL2 app is built with Unity, but has a dependency on a private DLL that uses EFCore 3.1.4. This DLL assists with DB operations and uses DbContext, etc.

> Currently, this DLL functions with other applications that actually
> run on the client machine (computer), so they have no issues
> connecting to the DB as they can do so via a file path.

Research I've Done:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20190911081541/http://www.mtirion.nl/2017/10/accessing-the-filesystem-with-unity-and-c-on-hololens/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions
- https://longqian.me/2017/02/08/hololens-file-transfer/

**Main Requirement / Question:**

**

> How can I use the existing DLL implementation (sample code below), to
> instantiate a connection to the DB File that resides on the computer
> *from the HoloLens*? This file is stored in C:/Program Files/...

**

**Accompanying Existing Code Sample**

```
// <summary>
// Helper function to create a SQLite Database Connection
// </summary>
// <param name="dbPath">Path to the SQLite Database file</param>
// <param name="password">Password to Database</param>
public static SqliteConnection CreateDBConnection(string dbPath, string password)
{
    // Create path if it doesn't exist
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(dbPath);
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    // Check if db file exists
    if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Create(dbPath);
        stream.Close();
    }

    SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=" + dbPath + CommonStrings.DB_Semicolon);
    connection.Open();
    using (SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT quote($password);";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$password", password);
        string escapedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar(); // Protects against SQL injection

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = " + escapedPassword + CommonStrings.DB_Semicolon;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create an online server. There are tons of them. This is better than the hassle you are going through. Moreover Windows in HL2 have other restrictions other than file storage requirements.

Comment: @Saif I understand why you'd suggest that, and I've certainly thought of it. The main complication is that several other applications are reading/writing to this SQLite DB on the computer, so the overhaul to a server is not trivial and has not been approved unless this is literally impossible to implement.

Comment: It appears that you're asking us to write the code to access the SQLite DB for you, which is not what Stack Overflow exists for. If that's not what you're asking, please edit your question to make it more explicit what the actual issue is with your current code.

Comment: @IanKemp I suppose that's on me, as I failed to explicitly state some things. Here is more context that I hope better explains my problem. I am the developer of the internal DLL my company is using for these other projects. I have already written this DLL/PCL that is in production use and implements DbContext, UnitOfWork, Repository Pattern, EFCore, uses SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher, blah blah. This only functions because in the DataSource=conStr of SqliteConnection I can pass in the actual file path of the DB as it resides on the same computer, I cannot do this on the HL2 as it is external.

Comment: That changes the question quite a lot - I would suggest you edit it to include the info from your comment, as comments can (theoretically) be deleted at any time, and it will be more visible that way. As for an answer, my naive suggestion would be to map the directory containing the DB as a network drive, then use the UWP `broadFileSystemAccess` permission to access it.

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks. Do my recent edits clarify it better?

Comment: @IanKemp I read about broadFileSystemAccess in one of the articles I mentioned, but I'll have to look into it more to see about potential implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get your requirements. As I understand, you want to use network protocol stack for USB-over-IP connection from HL to PC. This's not implemented now.

Particularly, you can't get access from Hololens to PC without a server running on PC. The server should handle a specific USB port commands to open a network connection. At the other party, HL should have a client to encode network protocol through USB.

Obviously, that is not an easy way. I recommend to open a normal TCP/IP connection from HL to PC.